# Delete files displayed in a listbox in c#?

Tags: c#, listboxitem

I have a listbox which displays the results of a file search in Windows.

What I'd like to be able to do is press the delete key whilst the item/s is highlighted and have the actual file deleted from the system.

I have it working for directories with Directory.Delete(obj.ToString()); but I can't get the following to work for files, if someone could help it would be appreciated. I get an illegal characters error after I press the Del key.

```
private void listBoxResults_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (btnFilesClicked == true)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
            {
                List<int> sItems = new List<int>();
                foreach (var obj in listBoxResults.SelectedIndices)
                {
                    sItems.Add(Convert.ToInt32(obj));
                }
                foreach (var obj in listBoxResults.SelectedItems)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        File.Delete(obj.ToString());
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                foreach (int item in sItems.OrderByDescending(x => x))
                {
                    listBoxResults.Items.RemoveAt(item);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you debug your application? Put a breakpoint and examine the value of obj.ToString()

Comment: How do you fill the ListBox? The problems seems to be there because when you retrieve an item from the list and try to call File.Delete, it complains about the item passed.

Comment: Since every object in .NET has a `.ToString()` method you should avoid using it for anything other than displaying a result. Can you cast to a specific object rather than using `.ToString()`?

Comment: Under this foreach (var obj in listBoxResults.SelectedItems) the selected item is {SelectedItem = "C:\\Temp\\Blank text file.txt\r\n"} and the obj.ToString value is obj = "C:\\Temp\\Blank text file.txt\r\n" by the look of it I need to get rid of the \r\n ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `ListBox.SelectedItems` Is an instance of IList which is not a generic implementation so it would give you only object instance...!

Have a look at this msdn [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox.selecteditems(v=vs.110).aspx) for `ListBox.SelectedItems`

Second thing When you will invoke ToString() on obj it's default implementation would return you type name.

This is the reason your code is not working exactly how you wanted.

```
try
{
    File.Delete(obj.ToString()); // this requires file name not the type name
}
```

You need to some how get the fileName first and then you can call `Delete` method like below.

```
try
{
    var fileName = GetFileName();
    File.Delete(fileName);
}
```